# Does the Microsoft Sync Framework require the Distributed Transaction Coordinator?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I have my own sync software which I have written for a SQL Server database but I am struggling to get MS DTC (distributed transaction coordinator) set up.  I have configured firewalls and services as per numerous articles and answers but none of it has worked.  So I am thinking of using the Microsoft Sync Framework instead.

Does the framework require DTC? If so, it wouldn't be a way around my problem.

Answer (score 0):

afaik, it doesn't require it. having said that, your Sync Fx implementation may need some additional coding if you have firewall issues/remote servers.